# How can I delete a corrupted directory? (`rm: cannot remove 'directory': Bad message`)

Tags: directory, rm, data-corruption

I am in a mounted VeraCrypt volume and have a corrupted directory that I wish to delete. When I attempt to `rm` the directory, I get a message like the following:

```
rm: cannot remove 'directory': Bad message
```

I see [a suggestion](https://superuser.com/a/1441014/705613) that a reboot will clear out corrupt files, but in the case of a mounted VeraCrypt volume obviously this won't happen.

I attempted to follow [a suggestion](https://superuser.com/a/197612/705613) to identify the inode of the directory (`ls -i`) but this yielded only a question mark.

So, how might I delete this file?

Comment: You probably cannot because the filesystem is corrupted… Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/547194/traversal-failed-u-bad-message-when-deleting-an-extremely-large-directory-in; https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/88109/how-to-delete-dat-files-rm-command-fails-with-bad-message

Comment: Can you not even see the contents of the directory?

Answer (score 1):

I had this error message in Nautilus and it could not work normally.  Listing the files with `ls` in Terminal showed some spurious Mac OS files or directories (like `.fseventsd` etc.) that I could not remove with `sudo rm -rf`  but could remove by repairing the partition element with `gnome-disks`.  Checking did not reveal any defect.  Actually, I had to repair twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to umount your disk and then **fsck** to check and fix the filesystem.
If this is a root partition disk, use some rescue or live linux disk to boot and then something like:

```
umount /mnt  # whatever is your mount path for this disk
fsck -y /dev/sdb
mount /mnt
```

(use your disk path instead of `sdb` and mounted path instead of `/mnt`).
If **fsck** is successfully fixing the filesystem, you shall be able to remove or manipulate your files and directories again.